# Paypal mass payment each recipient payment status

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk, masspay

I have used paypal mass pay payment systems and its worked correctly and payment is worked correctly. I have to know each mass pay transaction status. For ex: If we send to 100 receivers in a mass payment i need to know the payment success for these 100 receivers. Is there any api like this in paypal? Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an API to track the Mass Pay payments.
Instead, I would recommend you to use [IPN](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside). This will provide you notifications whenever a payment goes through.